# navigating to handlebars files

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I cannot navigate from my index.html file to a contact.handlebars HTML page that has a contact form.

Am I just misunderstanding how handlebars works?

I've tried taking away the extension completely.

```
<!-- Header -->
  <header>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="/Images/Small Logo.svg" alt="?" class="nav-logo"></a>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle">
    <!--NAVBAR-->
    <nav>  
        <ul class="nav-ul">
          <li class="nav-li">
            <a href="">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-li">
            <a href="answerswithamy.html">Answers with Amy<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-li">
            <a href="about.html">About<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-li">
            <a href="views/contact.handlebars">Contact<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
  </header>
```

the file path is correct.

I expect to have it navigate me to the handlebars file, displaying as an HTML page, but the page displays "Cannot GET /contact.handlebars"

Comment: You need to be much more specific then this. Add some code and explain what you expect it to do that doesn't work.

Comment: @Molda sorry, I pasted code, but it didn't seem to come through.

Comment: Can you include the directory structure of the files in question?

Comment: You need to include the node.js code with the view engine setup or if you just want to serve the handlebars file then include node.js code for serving static content.